# Holding after evaluation

Tags: hold, form-building

Given this little piece of code:

```
nenner = {2, 3, 4, 5};
zaehler = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
frac = Module[{}, RandomChoice[zaehler]/RandomChoice[nenner]];
FormFunction[{
    "first" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Number", 
    "Label" -> DisplayForm[frac] + DisplayForm[frac]|>}, f, 
    AppearanceRules -> {"Title" -> "Bruchrechnen", "Description" -> "Löse die Bruch-Aufgaben und gib das Ergebnis an", 
    "SubmitLabel" -> "Go!"}
]
```

I would like to get a form field labeled with e.g.  2/3 + 1/4 or something like that. But of course the expression gets evaluated. But if I hold it:

```
"Label" -> HoldForm[DisplayForm[frac] + DisplayForm[frac]]
```

the function "frac" is not evaluated any more.

How to solve this? I want the functions to evaluate, but the result to be held to get results in the required unevaluated form.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2517972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another interpretation of the OP's objective, based on some parts of the code that don't make sense (to me, as yet) unless `frac` is supposed to generate a new random fraction each time it is called.

```
nenner = {2, 3, 4, 5};
zaehler = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

(* new random frac each evaluation (via SetDelayed)
   I'd normally define it frac[] := ..., or even better
   randFrac[] := ... *)
frac := RandomChoice[zaehler]/RandomChoice[nenner];

FormFunction[{"first" ->
   <|"Interpreter" -> "Number",
    "Label" -> 
     HoldForm@Evaluate[f1 = frac] + HoldForm@Evaluate[f2 = frac]|>}, 
 If[#first == f1 + f2, "Right!", "Wrong. Try again?"] &,
 AppearanceRules -> {
   "Title" -> "Bruchrechnen",
   "Description" -> 
    "Löse die Bruch-Aufgaben und gib das Ergebnis an",
   "SubmitLabel" -> "Go!"}]
```

If you want to make sure that your random fractions do not reduce, so that the problem isn't simply `1 + 1`, filter out the denominators that are not coprime to the numerator:

```
frac := With[{z = RandomChoice[zaehler]},
  z/RandomChoice[Select[nenner, CoprimeQ[z, #] &]]]
```

Other issues:

1. You can localize `f1` and `f2` by wrapping the whole in `Module[{f1, f2}, <..code..> ]`. I didn't test this in the cloud, but it works on the desktop version.
2. The `Interpreter` format `"Number"` doesn't seem to accept fractions as numbers. It seems to me an oversight of WRI not to include fractions, given their interest in [Computer-Based Math](https://www.computerbasedmath.org). `"SemanticNumber"` will accept `58/15` for instance, as well as `58 fifteenths`. I'm not sure if it will accept German expressions. It did not accept `58 Fünfzehntel` nor `58 Fuenfzehntel`, which is the equivalent that Google Translate gave me. (I don't know if it's the right or wrong way to express 58/15.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"Label" -> With[{tmp = frac}, HoldForm[DisplayForm[tmp] + DisplayForm[tmp]]]
```

instead to evaluate before you hold.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call fraction it will evaluate. Therefore, e.g. let fraction return the nominator and denominator separately. And it is easier to use "StringForm". E.g.:

```
nenner = {2, 3, 4, 5};
zaehler = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
frac = Module[{}, {RandomChoice[zaehler], RandomChoice[nenner]}];
FormFunction[{"first" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Number", 
    "Label" -> StringForm["``/``=", Sequence @@ frac]|>}, f, 
 AppearanceRules -> {"Title" -> "Bruchrechnen", 
   "Description" -> "Löse die Bruch-Aufgaben und gib das Ergebnis an",
    "SubmitLabel" -> "Go!"}]
```

[image]